# Correct way to get login token from Pinterest API v3

Tags: javascript, pinterest

I am trying to allow the user to authenticate my app, then pull data from their profile using the Pinterest API v3. I am not really familiar with JavaScript or using API's but based on reading the docs I got this far:

```
<script>
    window.pAsyncInit = function() {
        PDK.init({
            appId: "xxxx",
            cookie: true
        });

        //login
        PDK.login({ scope : 'read_public' }, function(response){
            if (!response || response.error) {
                alert('Error occurred');
            } else {
                document.write(response);
            }
        });
        //end login

        //get board info
        var pins = [];
        var board_id='yyyy';
        PDK.request('/boards/'+board_id+'/pins/', function (response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occurred');
          } else {
                pins = pins.concat(response.data);
                if (response.hasNext) {
                  response.next();
                }
          }
        });
        document.write(pins);
        //end get board info
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js";
        pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'pinterest-jssdk'));
</script>
```

Can someone provide a working example of how to use the login function, and how to pass the token to PDK.request? NOTE: My PDK.request above works if I pass it an access token generated for testing from the Pinterest website.

Comment: What does `document.write(response);` give you?

Comment: You are calling PDK.request before login is done. Put the request where `document.write(response)` is.

Comment: But I need to login before I make the request right? Why would I put it beneath the api request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Pintrest Login</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p onclick="pintrest()">Click me</p>
    <div id="result"></div>
    </body>
<script>
function pintrest(){
    window.pAsyncInit = function() {
        PDK.init({
            appId: "Your api key",
            cookie: true
        });

        //login
        PDK.login({ scope : 'read_relationships,read_public' }, function(response){
            if (!response || response.error) {
              //  alert('Error occurred');
            } else {
               //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            }
        //get board info
        var pins = [];
        PDK.request('/v1/me/', function (response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            //alert('Error occurred');
          } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
              //  alert('success');
                console.log(PDK.getSession().accessToken);

                var yahoo = $( "#result" ).load( "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token="+PDK.getSession().accessToken+"&fields=counts" );
                console.log(yahoo);
                PDK.logout();
          }
        });

        //end get board info
        });
        //end login
    };

    (function(d, s, id){
        var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js";
        pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'pinterest-jssdk'));

    }
</script>

</body>
</html>



    <!DOCTYPE html>
     <head>
     <title>Pintrest Login</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     </head>
     <body>
     <p onclick="pintrest()">Click me</p>
     <div id="result"></div>
     </body>
    <script>
    function pintrest(){
        window.pAsyncInit = function() {
            PDK.init({
                appId: "You api key",
                cookie: true
            });

            //login
            PDK.login({ scope : 'read_relationships,read_public' }, function(response){
                if (!response || response.error) {
                  //  alert('Error occurred');
                } else {
                   //console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                }
            //get board info
            var pins = [];
            PDK.request('/v1/me/', function (response) {
              if (!response || response.error) {
                //alert('Error occurred');
              } else {
               console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                  //  alert('success');
                    console.log(PDK.getSession().accessToken);

                    var yahoo = $( "#result" ).load( "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/me/?access_token="+PDK.getSession().accessToken+"&fields=counts" );
                    console.log(yahoo);
                    PDK.logout();
              }
            });

            //end get board info
            });
            //end login
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, pjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//assets.pinterest.com/sdk/sdk.js";
            pjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, pjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'pinterest-jssdk'));

        }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>




I have used load method to get the followers as well as useful information
```

Comment: Hi, this code works fine. But one issue we have to fix more. Actually when we click on the link for authentication, popup is blocking by user browser. I research about this issue. And found that due to window.open function define inside settimeout function in sdk.js, we are getting such kind of problem.Any help will be appericiated